# Full traceback for chained exceptions when using 'raise from' syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Given the file `errors.py`:

```
from traceback import format_tb, extract_tb

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

class MySecondError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

try:
    try:
        raise MyError("Something specific has happened")
    except Exception as error:
        raise MySecondError("Something general has happened") from error
except Exception as error:
    print("".join(format_tb(error.__traceback__)))
```

When running `python errors.py` the output is:

```
  File "errors.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise MySecondError("Something general has happened") from error
```

The main problem with this is that only the traceback of the 'highest' error in the 'chain' (`MySecondError`) and there is no info on the wrapped error (`MyError`)

If I remove the final `try/except` wrapper so that the chained error is not caught, I get a much better output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptions.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise MyError("Something specific has happened")
__main__.MyError: Something specific has happened

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise MySecondError("Something general has happened") from error
__main__.MySecondError: Something general has happened
```

Which has the traceback of the full error chain **and** conjoining lines (`Traceback (most recent call last):`, `The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:`) **and** string representation of each error

Ideally I would like to capture these lines of output to direct them elsewhere (e.g. a logger)

One solution I have is to iterate over `error.__context__` and manually add the conjoining phrases:

```
except Exception as error:
    inner_error = error

    while inner_error:
        if inner_error is not error:
            print("\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n")

        print("Traceback (most recent call last):")
        print("".join(format_tb(inner_error.__traceback__) + [ str(error) ])) 
        inner_error = inner_error.__context__
```

Which works, but it is hacky and I would prefer to use some standard-library module which already handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`format_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) function:

```
from traceback import format_tb, format_exception

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

class MySecondError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

try:
    try:
        raise MyError("Something specific has happened")
    except Exception as error:
        raise MySecondError("Something general has happened") from error
except Exception as error:
    print("".join(format_exception(error.__class__, error, error.__traceback__)))
```

Gives:

```
$ python3 /tmp/a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise MyError("Something specific has happened")
MyError: Something specific has happened

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise MySecondError("Something general has happened") from error
MySecondError: Something general has happened
```

If you specify `chain=False` this function will not print conjoining exceptions but only the last one.

Comment: Thanks, should have spotted that when skimming the `traceback` module docs